# How can I extract hours and minutes from a datetime.datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, twitter, tweepy

I am required to extract the time of the day from the [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object returned by the *[created_at](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet)* attribute, but how can I do that?

This is my code for getting the datetime.datetime object.

```
from datetime import *
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(limit = 2)
t1 = datetime.strptime('Wed Jun 01 12:53:42 +0000 2011', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
for tweet in tweets:
   print (tweet.created_at - t1)
   t1 = tweet.created_at
```

I need to only extract the hour and minutes from `t1`.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I don't know how you want to format it, but you can do:

```
print("Created at %s:%s" % (t1.hour, t1.minute))
```

for example.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is it supposed to do? How does it work? What features of Python does it use? Can you link to documentation?

Answer (score 56):

If the time is **11:03**, then [afrendeiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754405/how-can-i-extract-hours-and-minutes-from-a-datetime-datetime-object/25754481#25754481) will print **11:3**.

You could zero-pad the minutes:

```
"Created at {:d}:{:02d}".format(tdate.hour, tdate.minute)
```

Or go another way and use `tdate.time()` and only take the hour/minute part:

```
str(tdate.time())[0:5]
```

Answer (score 41):

```py
import datetime
    
YEAR        = datetime.date.today().year     # the current year
MONTH       = datetime.date.today().month    # the current month
DATE        = datetime.date.today().day      # the current day
HOUR        = datetime.datetime.now().hour   # the current hour
MINUTE      = datetime.datetime.now().minute # the current minute
SECONDS     = datetime.datetime.now().second #the current second
    
print(YEAR, MONTH, DATE, HOUR, MINUTE, SECONDS)
```

```bash
2021 3 11 19 20 57
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 25):

It's easier to use the timestamp for these things since Tweepy gets both:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t1)).strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Answer (score 11):

datetime has fields `hour` and `minute`. So to get the hours and minutes, you would use `t1.hour` and `t1.minute`.

However, when you subtract two datetimes, the result is a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which only has the `days` and `seconds` fields. So you'll need to divide and multiply as necessary to get the numbers you need.

Comment: Re *"which only has the days and seconds fields"*: The [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) *"Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally"* (also microseconds). What is the explanation? As the OP seems to have left the building, perhaps somebody can chime in?