# Time and function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, datetime, time

Are there anyway of making a timefunction which returns time and not years? For example:

```
enter code here

def time(t):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M")
print(time('6:00'))
```

If I write this I will get: 1900-01-01 06:00:00, but I only want 06:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract hours and minutes from a datetime.datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754405/how-to-extract-hours-and-minutes-from-a-datetime-datetime-object)

Comment: Why not just print the argument you're passing to the function? It seems to be what you need...

Comment: Because I need to use the function on different occasions thats why

Comment: I need a function not only use it for the print i showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a datetime object. You can format a datetime object with `strftime`

```
import datetime


def time(t):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M")
    
print(f"{time('06:00').strftime('%H:%M')}")
```

Comment: I see! Are there no way of returning it directly to the function so that I dont have to write  .strftime('%H:%M') everytime?

Comment: I mean by editing the function to directly give out what you just wrote?

Comment: sure, but then it starts really not making any sense because your really return your input and not even a datetime object you could do other stuff with..`return datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M").strftime('%H:%M')`