# String time convert to only timestamp using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a time 00:11:21.600000 like this in each row of excel I want to convert to time stamp in hrs and mins

Comment: I have a column df['time] and wanto convert to time

Comment: doesn't it your answer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754405/how-to-extract-hours-and-minutes-from-a-datetime-datetime-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding onto Juilian Focks answer, if you have a column named `df["time"]`, you can convert each element into timestamp object by iterating over it as :

```
from datetime import datetime
for  i in range(0,len(df["time"])):
 df["time"][i] = df["time"][i].strftime("%H:%M")
```

or you could use list comprehension as :

```
dt_array = [x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in df["time"]]
```

then `dt_array` contains whole column as datetime object

Comment: still getting this error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.time

Comment: that means you are trying to convert something into datetime which is already datetime. `df["time"]` is already datetime.

Comment: but datatype of that column is object

Comment: yes, it is an object, a `datetime object`

Comment: I just edited answer, please test if it works for you.

Comment: okay then I have 2 columns df['time] which is start time and df['end'] which is end time and now want to find time difference

Comment: you can just do end_time - start_time if both are datetime object. But you might need to create a new question and accept my answer as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime


your_time = datetime.strptime('00:11:21.600000', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Then you have a datetime object `your_time` on which you can perform different actions, for example:

Get str with hours and minutes: `your_time.strftime('%H:%M')`

For more methods see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: df['newcolname'] = datetime.strptime(df['time'], '%H:%M:%S.%f') getting below error

Comment: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: it is because you are trying to apply that strptime to whole column, you have to iterate over each item and convert it to datetime object like Julian suggested.

Comment: Could you guide me on how to iterate over each item? I am learning
Thank you!

Comment: df['newcolname'] = pd.to_datetimee(df['time'], '%H:%M:%S:%f')  getting below errorValueError: time data '00:45:36' does not match format '%H:%M:%S:%f' (match)

Comment: Two things: 1.: You use `':%f'` instead of `'.%f'` 2.: I was assuming your time formats were uniform '00:11:21.600000 like this', if you have different formats like '00:45:36' you would need to make them uniform or handle edge cases. E.g.: `datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S.%f') if '.' in time_str else datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S')`