# How to extract hours, minutes and secods from datetime.fromtimestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

from response i get date time stamp like this `'1663935188183'`. I used python `datetime.fromtimestamp()` function and print date in full format `'2022-09-23 14:13:08.183000'`

My question is. Can i extract from function above just hours, minutes and secods ?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities. I would recommend a look into the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/  
There you will find everything you need. attributes that give you the values one by one, strftime(), isoformat().

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date) and [How can I extract hours and minutes from a datetime.datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25754405/10197418)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```py
>> from datetime import datetime

# Be carefule this will raise ValueError: year 54698 is out of range
# you have to divide timestamp by 1e3 if your timestamp is in milliseconds
>> timestamp = 1663935188183/1e3
>> date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
>> date.hour, date.minute, date.second
(14, 13, 8)
```

Comment: that timestamp is probably milliseconds, not nanoseconds. so correct divisor is 1e3. also, your answer is missing how to extract hours seconds etc. from the datetime object.

Comment: thank you for your comment, forgot to mention that we can also string format the date to obtain ```hours```, ```minutes```, ```seconds``` and ```nanoseconds``` using the following function ```date.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')```